# jquery slide container height when childrens are shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have a div with children elements that are hidden except for the first child.

I want a div container to slide down when his children are changing from display none to show.

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen</div>  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen</div>
  </div>

<button id="see_all">see all</button>
```

Just check [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/06ff3fon/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all that you're looking for is a sliding animation, then simply change

```
$('.container').find('.block').addClass('active');
```

to

```
$('.container').find('.block').slideDown(500);
```

If you still need the opened blocks to have the class `active` then you can set it in the callback:

```
$('.container').find('.block').slideDown(500, function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

PS: Your fiddle is missing jQuery ;-)

**Edit: updated answer below**

If you don't want all blocks to slide down separately then we need to go about it in a different way.

*Option 1*
The easiest option would be to wrap the hidden blocks in another div. Then we can simply slide down this new container:

```
$('#see_all').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').find('.hidden-blocks').slideDown(500);
});
```

An example of this in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/06ff3fon/3/

*Option 2*
If for whatever reason, you can't wrap the other blocks then the only option I can think of is to set the height of the container, so the other blocks are out of view. Then we animate the height of the container so it slides down, revealing the blocks.

```
$('#see_all').on('click', function() {
  var $container = $('.container');
  var containerHeight = $container.height() + 10;// +10 to fix silly collapsing bottom margin
  var $blocks = $container.find('.block');
  var totalBlockHeight = 0;
  $container.height(containerHeight);// this will overwrite the initial 'auto' height
  $blocks
    .addClass('active')
    .each(function() {
      totalBlockHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
    });
  $container.animate(
    { height: totalBlockHeight + 'px' },
    500,
    function() {}
  )
});
```

Again an example in your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/06ff3fon/2/

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to save with jquery ;). The thing is that i don't want each block to slide down. Just the container

Comment: Ah ok, I get it. I've updated my answer with 2 options. I'm positive that one of them will be what you're looking for :)

Comment: Option 2 is no good because the text is dynamic. But I don't know how i didn't think of option 1. Thanks!!